# Combine Google My Business API V1 and V4.9

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api

In the OAuth Playground 2.0 of Google i managed to get  my accounts / locations using this URL:

V1 API
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/xxx/locations?readMask=name

For the reviews we need to switch to the older V4 API:
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/xxx/locations/xxx/reviews

This is workable in Playground but I want to build a Python script to fetch the reviews.

I can get the accounts in Python using the V1 API:

```
from googleapiclient import sample_tools
from googleapiclient.http import build_http
MyBusinessAccount, flags = sample_tools.init(argv, "mybusinessaccountmanagement", "v1", __doc__,     __file__, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage")

output = MyBusinessAccount.accounts().list().execute()
print("List of Accounts:\n")
print(json.dumps(output, indent=2) + "\n")
```

But how do I access the Reviews using Python? As `MyBusinessAccount` is initialized as a V1 API.

The Google documentation is not really clear on this. Also it seems the V4 API is becoming deprecated, but the reviews are not yet switched to V1.

Ideas?

- OAuth Playground 2.0 testing works fine
- V1 API example works as expected but I can't access V4 methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and it turned out I had to enable the following API, even though it's not mentioned in the docs anywhere I could see and doesn't appear to show up in API library searches:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com

I also had to download the discovery doc, as there is no discovery URL for this service. I found that here:

https://developers.google.com/static/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json

```py
discovery_file = "/some/path/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json"

sample_tools.init(
    argv, 
    "mybusiness", 
    "v4", 
    __doc__,
    __file__, 
    scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage", 
    discovery_filename=discovery_file
)
```

After enabling and using the discovery doc from a file I was able to grab reviews from my locations. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your comment.
When reading this new JSON file, how can I see which methods i can use?

With the V1 API
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1

output = MyBusinessAccount.accounts().list().execute() is a valid method. 

But for the dowloaded JSON this isn't a valid method any more.

How do i translate the JSON to the possible methods to use?  (I dont see execute() anywhere in the JSON, but still can be used?)